When and where does the Disney film "Aladdin" take place?
I don't know when and where the Disney film Aladdin takes place. I want a lot of good evidence and a clear location and time.

If you've found an answer, you should post it as an answer (preferably with the evidence, we won't find it boring!), rather than editing it into the question.

This reads as a ChatGPT prompt and is IMO not an acceptable tone for writing questions on this site.

Doesn't the movie actually state that they're in Agrabah?

@Flater Yeah, that wasn’t what it originally said. Someone has edited it to sound like a ChatGPT prompt.

The intro narration states that Aladdin takes place in the fictional kingdom of Agrabah, located near the Jordan River. The time period isn't mentioned, but it evokes the setting of One Thousand and One Nights, which is set in the Islamic Golden Age during the 8th or 9th century.
